# How does the Gunzerker / Salvador's Just Got Real skill work?

Tags: borderlands-2

I just got a Purple [Vengeful Beast](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Beast) Class Mod which gives +5 to the [Just Got Real](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Just_Got_Real) skill, among other bonuses. The Just Got Real skill is described as:

> It increases damage with all guns the lower your health is.

I was wondering how Just Got Real works exactly and have the following questions:

- Does it still give a damage bonus even if I'm at full health? If yes, then by what percentage of the maximum damage bonus is this?
- Does it work when I'm in FFYL (Fight For Your Life), where I have zero health?
- Does anyone know how its damage bonus is computed? What percentage of the maximum damage bonus will I get depending on my remaining health?

Answer (score 1):

*Disclaimer: I cannot (am too lazy to) test it definitely righ away (which is trivial given Marcus' practice dummy, respec station and explosives). This answer is based on general experience and discusions around here somewhere.*

Skills that give bonuses depending on current health or shields use following rules:

- Being at full health grants no bonus (verifiable by lack of bonus icon).
- Maximum attainable bonus is at zero health, in Fight For Your LIfe (yes, it should work in FFYL).
- Dependency is linear. 50% health => 50% bonus. 25% health => 75% bonus.